# Core Data, Search Controller and Table View

Tags: iphone, core-data, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have integrated the search function to my app to query core data/.sqlite and it works ok. But I have a problem and I am not sure which class configuration should I look at, could someone points me to the light, thanks

Basically my model is this

**TableView 1**
Display Product Category
selectRow --> TableView2

**TableView 2**
Display Products of selected Category
selectRow  --> TableView3

As I integrated the UISearchBar in **TableView 1**, I wish to have the function when people search the product they want and it will **show up the product's name** right away in the table view. I tried, but the result is showing the **Category** which contains the "searched product".

So, how could I get this to show up correctly and which section of configuration should I look at?

```
    UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];  

[self performSelector:@selector(setSearchDisplayController:) withObject:searchDisplayController];

[searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];  
[searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];  
[searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDelegate:self];
[searchDisplayController release];  
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame.size.height)];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();

    self.filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] count]];
}
```

Is it this part of the code?
Thanks

### Update with more info:

**Configure Cell**

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSManagedObject *entity = nil;
if (self.searchIsActive){  // Configure the cell to show the searched item's name  
entity = [[self filteredListContent] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
} else {// Configure the cell to show the category's name 
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];  
entity = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
} 
cell.textLabel.text = [entity valueForKey:@"nameEN"]; 
}
```

**The Search Predicate**

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY products.nameEN CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
self.filteredListContent = [[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```

**The Core Data Structure**

```
Category{  
    nameEN  
    products <- one to many relation ->> Product.productcat
}

Product{ 
    nameEN  
    spec  
    productcat <<-- many to one relation-> Category.products
}
```

*Thank you.*

Comment: Why do both entities have a `nameEN` attribute? In your code below you seem to searching for Products that share an nameEN value with a Product. Why not just use the relationship instead?

Comment: the nameEN represent the category name and product name and since there is only abt 12 categories but hundreds of products, i just want to provide a more user-friendly function for users as i can see from the users review, not all users know exactly what category the products they want belongs to.

Comment: Just because the users don't understand something does not mean you have to alter the data model. The data model should model/simulate the logical relationships within the data only. It is the role of the controller and UI to display that data in a meaningful way to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data model has a `Product` entity and a `Category` entity and your fetches are returning `Category` objects instead of `Product` objects, then you have the wrong entity set for your fetch.

[*ignore following as it applies to a different type of search* -- techzen]
<strike>You usually create a separate fetch for the search because every time the users enters new characters in the search, the predicate for the fetch must change.</strike>

### Update:

Okay, I misunderstood the type of search you were implementing. You are filtering the return of an existing fetch instead of fetching based on the entered search.

Looking at the predicate and data model in your update I think it clear that the predicate will only work against an array of `Category` objects. This:

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY products.nameEN CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
```

... can only filter `Category` objects because only the `Category` object has an attribute of `products`. This predicate says, "Match all Catergory objects in which any related Product object has a nameEn attribute value that contains the search text."

Remember as well that the array you are filtering here:

```
self.filteredListContent = [[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

...is an array of `Category` objects and not `Product` objects.

I think you need to rethink your UI design. Your TableView1 defaults to displaying a list of `Category` objects but you want your search of that table to display a list of `Product` objects. That will confuse the user. The user will expect a search on a table of `Category` objects to return a subset of `Category` objects.

However, with the existing design, you can produce an array of `Product` objects with the current code by creating a new array of `Product` objects by apply the `@distinctUnionOfObjects` collection operator:

```
self.filteredListContent = [[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray *distinctProducts=[self.filteredListContent valueForKey:@"products.@distinctUnionOfObjects.enName"];
```

... `distinctProducts` will now be an array of `Product` objects matching the search criteria. Use that array in `configureCell:atIndexPath` (you may need to resort it.)

Comment: thanks, so, do you mean I need to create a new FRC for that? I have included more code in my question, would be great if you could give me some hints. thanks

Comment: thank you so much, but I tried your solution, no luck for me...keeps saying Entity "Category" is not key value coding compliant....etc So, I end up see my comment below, but still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried these at the configure cell part

```
        NSDictionary *distinctProducts=[self.filteredListContent valueForKey:@"products"];
    NSLog(@"what are products:%@",distinctProducts);
    NSArray *listofProductsName = [distinctProducts valueForKey:@"nameEN"];
    NSLog(@"whatup: %@",listofProductsName);
    NSArray *entity = [listofProductsName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = entity;
```

But then I could convert the name to show...it said _NFSet isEqualToString: ....etc terminated NSException.. though the NSLog of listofProductsName show up the right products name list.

Comment: I think your design is trying to logically superimpose two separate tables over each other. You start with a table of `Categories` but you want the search to return a list of `Products`. That is possible but difficult to manage and requires considerable duplication of code because one code block has to handle the display of `Categories` and the other the display of `Products`.

Comment: You are getting the exception because the tableview row count is not synced to the length of the `listOfProductsName` array but instead to the length of fetched results controller's `fetchedObjects` array. Like I said above, if you want to use two different entities this way, you will have to duplicate all the tableview management code. In this immediate case, it means using the length of `listOfProductsName` in `numberOfRowsInSection`. Your design is very complicated and doesn't match the design of the API very well.

Comment: as mentioned above, the reason to integrate this feature is because some users don't know what the products belong to which category, but displaying a table list of hundreds of products with thumbnail and provide a search there might be memory consumption, so i want to put this at the category table, so if user know the product category, they can browse or if they don't know, they can search for it and access directly.

Comment: It's a common misperception that long tables plus complex cells e.g. with thumbnails means high memory consumption. Tableviews only have enough cells in memory to cover the visible screen. They rotate actual cell instances as needed. E.g. If it takes 10 cells to cover the screen then the tableview would have at most 11 cells active at anyone time. You can display a tableview with thousands of logical rows using the same memory as one displaying just 11. You probably want a table of products that is indexed e.g. like the Contacts App. Or you can used nested tables broken down by range e.g. A-D